# How can sieve of Eratosthenes be implemented in O(n) time complexity?

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, primes, sieve-of-eratosthenes

There is implementation of this algorithm of finding prime numbers upto `n` in `O(n*log(log(n))` time complexity. How can we achieve it in `O(n)` time complexity?

Comment: Why do you tag C++ and Java, as if saying "just give me the code in any of the languages"? If you ask about an algorithm don't tag any languages. If you ask a specific implementation please show us what you have done so far and tag only the appropriate language.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can perform the Sieve of Eratosthenes to determine which numbers are prime in the range `[2, n]` in `O(n)` time as follows:

- For each number `x` in the interval `[2, n]`, we compute the minimum prime factor of `x`. For implementation purposes, this can easily be done by keeping an array --- say `MPF[]` --- in which `MPF[x]` represents the minimum prime factor of `x`. Initially, you should set `MPF[x]` equal to zero for every integer `x`. As the algorithm progresses, this table will get filled.
- Now we use a for-loop and iterate from `i = 2` upto `i = n` (inclusive). If we encounter a number for which `MPF[i]` equals `0`, then we conclude immediately that `i` is prime since it doesn't have a least prime factor. At this point, we mark `i` as prime by inserting it into a list, and we set `MPF[i]` equal to `i`. Conversely, if `MPF[i]` does *not* equal `0`, then we know that `i` is composite with minimum prime factor equal to `MPF[i]`.
- During each iteration, after we've checked `MPF[i]`, we do the following: compute the number `y_j = i * p_j` for each prime number `p_j` less than or equal to `MPF[i]`, and set `MPF[y_j]` equal to `p_j`.

This might seem counterintuitive --- why is the runtime `O(n)` if we have two nested loops? The key idea is that every value is set exactly one, so the runtime is `O(n)`. This [website](https://cp-algorithms.com/algebra/prime-sieve-linear.html) gives a C++ implementation, which I've provided below:

```
const int N = 10000000;
int lp[N+1];
vector<int> pr;

for (int i=2; i<=N; ++i) {
    if (lp[i] == 0) {
        lp[i] = i;
        pr.push_back (i);
    }
    for (int j=0; j<(int)pr.size() && pr[j]<=lp[i] && i*pr[j]<=N; ++j)
        lp[i * pr[j]] = pr[j];
}
```

The array `lp[]` in the implementation above is the same thing as `MPF[]` that I described in my explanation. Also, `pr` stores the list of prime numbers.

Comment: I got it. Thanks :)

Comment: surely it does not scale though. if you don't think it's right, please provide actual run times for e.g. `n1 = 1B` and `n2 = 1.5B` so we can calculate the [Empirical orders of growth](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analysis_of_algorithms#Empirical_orders_of_growth) as `log(t2/t1) / log(1.5)`. for comparison, simple bit-packed  non-segmented (contiguous) sieve of Eratosthenes on odds exhibits ~n^1.06 behavior on that range [on ideone](https://ideone.com/fapob) (that's old timings, current ideone is bound to be faster, but the orders of growth can't change much).

Answer (score 0):

Well, if the algorithm is O(n*log(n)) you generally can’t do better without changing the algorithm.

The complexity is O(n*log(n)). But you can trade between time and resources: By making sure you have O(log(n)) computing nodes running in parallel, it would be possible to do it in O(n).

Hope I didn’t do your homework...

Comment: Apart from the log log, would you care to elaborate?

Comment: not everything is parallelizable. not every parallelization improves complexity.  the number of available CPUs is usually limited and fixed. there's cost to communications between threads, if there is such a need. etc. etc. etc. all this must be addressed specifically for a given algorithm. otherwise it's empty talk.

Comment: Yes, but the sieve is easily parallelizable. Since no code was given, this looked more like a theoretical question in a computer science lecture. When I studied, we could assume a large enough machine. And in practice, even O(n^2) can be much faster than O(n) even for large values of n before it turns, so what gives - it's a theoretical answer to a theoretical question.

Comment: no *fixed* amount of resources (like available cores) will ever change complexity one iota.

Comment: Ah, you are too practical... ;-)